# Is there a way to view Windows recycle bin information from Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, external-hard-drive, recycle-bin

I have several Windows hard drives with various files in their respective recycling bin directories:

```
$RECYCLE.BIN
```

Is there a way to view information about these files to tell if they are no longer needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows XP and earlier, you can use the command line utility `rifiuti` to read the INFO2 file.

From Windows Vista and newer, use `strings -el -f \$I*` from the `/$RECYCLE.BIN/{SID}/` directory.  This will print out a listing of the original filenames for each file in the Recycle Bin.

`-el` tells strings to look for 16-bit little endian character encoding;

`-f` tells strings to print filenames.